# Maven project: Can't use external jar in Eclispe (UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: eclipse, maven, jogl

I am trying to use the external jars JOGL and GlueGen in a Maven poject. When running the code in Eclipse, i get this error message:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYUY1.png)

I am including both external jars as dependencies in the pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- JOGL & Gluegen -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Strangely, other other extrenal jars like Guava that are included as dependencies loaded from Maven's central repo work fine.

Help to fix this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: The error says that a `dll` cannot be opened. Could you give explanation about that?

Comment: I am not sure why Java is looking for a .dll file, but it might have something to do with this: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL#Native_JARs_vs._native_library_files

Comment: JogAmp (GlueGen, JOGL, JOAL, JOCL, ...) contains some Java libraries that rely on native libraries. I advise you to test JOGL alone without Maven as a first step in order to check whether your problem comes from Maven or from JOGL. Do you use a virus scanner? Please ask your question on the official JogAmp forum as your question is very specific to JOGL and most contributors don't come here. By the way, JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation uses JOGL with Maven and it works like a charm: https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/tree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the artifact id `gluegen-rt-main` instead of `gluegen-rt` like me:
[Maven build file of JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation](https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/tree/pom.xml#n308)

If it's not enough, you'll have to stop using Maven and maybe to disable automated native library loading ([this is explained in the JOGL user's guide](https://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/#automatednativelibraryloading)).